# How to initialize constant such as "public static final Integer" in java from args[] in main method (or any)

Tags: java, initialization, arguments, constants

I'm basically a beginner in Java and I am trying to figure out this problem:

my project uses (integer)constant through many classes and I need to set up this constant from file/argument of programm and I have no idea how. I could remove "final" statement but that is against all conventions.

How to resolve this? What is best way to avoid it? Please help me :)

short example:

```
public class App {
    public static final int k;  
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        k = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); // does not work ... sure but how? 
    }
}
```

EDIT: public STATIC void main ... (it was missing static)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could have each class that requires this value access to a shared pool of data, the `ApplicationContext`, where the value `X` would reside as a constant:

```
public final class ApplicationContext {

    public static abstract class Worker {

        private final ApplicationContext mApplicationContext;

        public Worker(final ApplicationContext pApplicationContext) {
            this.mApplicationContext = pApplicationContext;
        }


        public final ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
            return this.mApplicationContext;
        }

    }

    private final int mX;

    ApplicationContext(final String[] pArgs) {
        this.mX = pArgs[0];
    }


    public final int getX() {
        return this.mX();
    }

}
```

By having all relevant classes extend `ApplicationContext.Worker`, we can ensure access to the constant value without having to rely upon a `static` implementation because all classes will receive a reference to `ApplicationContext` upon construction.

Answer (score 2):

You can only use this kind of functionality within the `static { }` block.

I'd recommend making the constant itself private, and accessible only through `public static` getter methods. This should be a suitable architecture.

Comment: I suppose this could work for me well, but isn't it violation of constants?

Comment: True, however I believe that this is sufficient protection for a value that is specified via the command line.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `static{}` block:

```
public class App {
    public static final int k;

    static {
        String kvalue = "";
        try
        {
            // Insert some code to open a file and read a value from it.
            kvalue = "<value from file>";
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            // handle any exceptions opening the file
        }
        finally
        {
            k = Integer.parseInt( kvalue );
        }
    }

    public static void main( final String[] args ) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty good for files, but how about program arguments? Could it be modified somehow?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `static final` variables can only be initialized in static blocks.

Comment: Could you read from a file and initialize the variable in a `static` block?

Comment: Sure. You could either create a method that will read and initialize the static field, which will get invoked in the static block. Or you could place the code in a `try-catch` block directly in the static block.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot add static statement before main method. I am talking about "public static void main" ofc

Comment: Ok by static block you mean something like: 

static {
k = Integer.parseInt(new SomeReader("InputFile.txt).readLine());
} 

?